# How do i know if Today is between Christmas and Epiphany in PHP?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I thought this would be a doddle but i am finding it harder than i thought.

Every day, I want to check whether today is in between Christmas (25 Dec) and Epiphany (6 Jan) ie Christmastide.

The problem i'm having is to do with the years as the year changes in the middle of that period.

My basic if statement would be:

```
$this_year_today = date("d-M-Y");
$christmas = date('d-M-Y', strtotime("25 December ".$year));
$epiphany = date('d-M-Y', strtotime("6 January ".$year));

if(($this_year_today >= $christmas) && ($this_year_today < $epiphany)){
      $season= "Christmastide";}
```

BUT if today is after christmas 2017 then epiphany date is 2018, but if today is before epiphany then christmas is 2016.  Doing my head in a bit.  WHat's the easiest way to do it.  I tried using strtotime to say "last Christmas" but didnt seem to work...

Thx

Comment: What about don't using the year? If you don't use the year, you can compare the date and say `christmasdate < date < epiphany`. For this i would format the date like `M-d`. This will be much easier to handle

Comment: @SacrumDeus `'12-26' < '12-31' && '12-31' < '1-6'`…? That's never gonna be true…

Comment: Your date should be `1226` and `1231`. With this, you can compare those easily, because 1231 is greater then 1226 and `0106` is smaller than `1231`. Maybe it'll helps a little

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function isChristmastide() {
    $month = date('n');
    $day = date('j');
    return ($month == 12 && $day >= 25) || ($month == 1 && $day <= 6);
}

echo isChristmastide() ? 'Ho ho ho' : 'No no no';
```

Other alternative:

```
$today = date('nj');
return 1225 <= $today || $today <= 16;
```

Though I find the readability questionable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, no need to get confuse with year.

```
$current_day = date('j'); //get Day of the month without leading zeros
$current_month = date('n'); //get Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros
$season = '';
switch($current_month):
    case 1:
        $season = $current_day<=6 ? 'Christmastide' : 'Not Christmastide';            
        break;
    case 12:
        $season = $current_day>=25 ? 'Christmastide' : 'Not Christmastide';
        break;
    default: 
        $season = 'Not Christmastide';
        break;
endswitch;
echo $season;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/5rNvA)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but perhaps you could try like this using numeric values for time rather than a date?

```
$year=date('Y');
$nextyear=$year+1;

$now=time();
$christmas = strtotime("25 December $year");
$epiphany = strtotime("6 January $nextyear");

$season=( $now >= $christmas && $now <= $epiphany ) ? 'Christmastide' : 'Not Christmastide';

echo $season;
```

Comment: if 3rd jan you'd want to be checking christmas of last year

Comment: you could consider the previous year if the current month is january, or the current year if the current month is december. With that result, you check if the date is greater than 25 december, or less than 6th january respectively

Answer (score 0):

thanks to frankiehf, this should now be the answer:

```
$month = date('M');
$year = date('Y');
$last_year = $year-1;
$next_year = $year+1;

if($month == "Jan"){
  $christmas = date('d-M-Y', strtotime("25 December ".$last_year));
    $epiphany = date('d-M-Y', strtotime("6 January ".$year));}
else{
  $christmas = date('d-M-Y', strtotime("25 December ".$year));
    $epiphany = date('d-M-Y', strtotime("6 January ".$next_year));}

if(($this_year_today >= $christmas) && ($this_year_today < $epiphany)){
      $season= "Christmastide";}
```

Comment: That's rather overcomplicated.